# Upgrade and jailbreak 8.1 -> 8.4

Tags: ios, itunes, iphone, jailbreak

I have an iPhone 4s. Currently, iOS 8.1 is installed, but it isn't jailbroken. When my device is connected to iTunes, it says I can update to iOS 8.4.1.

What is the correct way to get a jailbroken version of iOS 8.4 onto my phone? Is it possible?

Comment: Check this guide ; http://www.guidemyjailbreak.com/jailbreak-iphone-4s-ios-81/

Comment: @vembutech the link is useless it is for 8.1. Maybe the question isn't clear - so trying to refine it. Now the iPhone and the iTunes offers me 8.4.1 to download. (not 8.4). The 8.4.1 as far as i known isn't possible jailbreak (it closed the Tiag's hole). So, the question is still the same: How to install get an jailbroken 8.4 to my iphone. (e.g. i do not want jailbreak 8.1, but want the 8.4 - the lastest jaibreak-able iOS in my iPhone.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem, but in my case with iOS 8.1 jailbroken on a 5s.  Taig won't work as it requires at least 8.1.3 which I don't have, the legit upgrade method goes straight to 8.4.1.  Do update this thread if you find a fix.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, not only is it possible to upgrade and jailbreak, it's very easy.

## [Updating to iOS 8.4](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204204)

1. Install the latest version of iTunes on your computer.
2. Tap [here](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios8.4/ipsw/031-25968-20150630-5CA12418-1B91-11E5-A4E7-6265BE268FF7/iPhone4,1_8.4_12H143_Restore.ipsw) to download the iOS 8.4 `.ipsw` file (operating system).
3. Plug your device into your computer.
4. In iTunes, select your device.
5. In the Summary pane use the following on the Check for Update box.

   - Windows: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Click
   - Mac: <kbd>Option</kbd> + Click
6. Select the `.ipsw` file and update.

## [Jailbreaking iOS 8.4](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2015/06/how-to-jailbreak-ios-8-4-using-taig-jailbreak.html)

1. Download the [TaiG jailbreaking software](http://www.iphonehacks.com/download-taig-jailbreak).
2. Connect your device to your computer using the USB cable.
3. Temporarily Disable Passcode from Settings > Touch ID & Passcode.
4. Temporarily turn off Find my iPhone from Settings > iCloud > Find my iPhone.
5. On Windows, launch the jailbreaking application as an Administrator. To do this, right click on the executable file and select the “Run as Administrator” option.
6. The software will take some time to detect your device. Once you confirm that it is showing the correct firmware version, deselect the 3K Assistant 2.3.0 (TaiG’s App Store), just below Cydia 1.1.18.
7. Click on the green Start button to proceed.
8. After the jailbreak is complete, your device will reboot automatically, and you should see the Cydia icon on the Home screen.

Comment: My english isnt the best and probably therefore the question isn't understandable enough. Now the iPhone and the iTunes offers me **8.4.1** to download. (not 8.4). The 8.4.1 as far as i known isn't possible jailbreak (it closed the Tiag's hole). So, the question is still the same: How to install get an jailbroken 8.4 to my iphone.

Comment: Also reverted you edit, because the edit removes the details about the versions. Please, if you edit a question (it is welcomed), but *please* do not alter it's main points.